# Beamer TOC: changing color and shape for subsection items in TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, formatting

The default items for subsection in TOC are balls (no-nummered). I would like to use blue triangles, like the symbol `\blacktriangleright` but blue color. Any idea?

Comment: Using which theme, please?

Comment: The theme is CambridgeUS.

Comment: Please add this new information to your question. I've provided an answer below.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a code simplification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine the `subsection in toc` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\leavevmode\leftskip=5.65ex%
  \llap{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\textcolor{structure}{$\blacktriangleright$}}\kern1ex}%
  \inserttocsubsection\par%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Depending on your specifications, you might also need to redefine the `subsection in toc shaded` template.

[image]